# expectation of stopped local time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I would like to solve
exercise 2.8  in  Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion from Daniel Revuz,Marc Yor.

Let $B$ a linear Brownian motion and $a \leq x \leq y \leq b$ prove that :

$E_x[L^y_{T_a \wedge T_b}]=2(x-a)(b-y)/(b-a)$

where $T_a:=\inf\{t \geq 0| B_t=a\},T_b:=\inf\{t \geq 0| B_t=b\}$.
and $T_a \wedge T_b:=min(T_a,T_b)$.

My idea is to use Tankas formula:

$|B_t-y|-|B_0-y|-L_t^y= \int_0^t sign(B_t-y) d B_t$
and applying optional stopping theorem because $\int_0^t sign(B_t-y) d B_t$ is a martingal. Then one obtains

$E_x[|B_{T_a \wedge T_b}-y|]-|x-y|  -E_x[L^y_{T_a \wedge T_b}]=0$.
Now, I'm struggle with the term $E_x[|B_{T_a \wedge T_b}-y|]$.
Every idea is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to directly compute $\mathbb{E}^x[|B_{T_a \wedge T_b} - y|]$ by noting that $B_{T_a \wedge T_b} \in \{a,b\}$. Indeed, we have
$$\mathbb{E}^x[|B_{T_a \wedge T_b} - y|] = |a-y| \mathbb{P}^x (T_a < T_b) + |b-y| \mathbb{P}^x(T_b < T_a)$$
It is well known that $\mathbb{P}^x(T_a < T_b) = \frac{b-x}{b-a}$ and $\mathbb{P}^x(T_b < T_a) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$. Hence 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}^x[L_{T_a \wedge T_b}^y] &= \mathbb{E}^x[|B_{T_a \wedge T_b} - y|] - (y-x) \\& 
= (y-a) \frac{b-x}{b-a} + (b-y) \frac{x-a}{b-a} - (y-x) \\&
= 2 \frac{(x-a)(b-y)}{b-a}
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot.