# Local time and $\int_0^t \operatorname{sgn}(B_t-x)\,dB_t$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I would like to compute the expectation of the stopped local time $L_t^x$ with underlying Brownian Motion $B_t$ with $B_0=x$. Set

$T_a=\inf\{ s \geq 0 \mid B_s=a\}$
with $y<x<a$.

The target of interest is 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_{T_a}^y]$. I would like apply optional stopping theorem. We have by Tanaka's Formula
$$|B_t-y|-|B_0-y|=\int_0^t \operatorname{sgn}(B_s-y)\,dB_s+L_t^y.$$

But for this I have to prove $\int_0^{T_a} \operatorname{sgn}(B_t-y)\,dB_t$ is bounded.

Nevertheless assuming this. We obtain 
$|a-y|-|x-y|=\mathbb{E}_x[L_{T_a}^y]$.

We have: 
$|a-y|-|x-y|=a-y-|x-y|=a-x$.

So I'm not very sure about this computation. Thanks for every comment

There is some other Question which arises. If we have the case $x<y<a$ we would obtain

$\mathbb{E}_x[L_{T_a}^y]=a+x-2y$. For example for $x=0$ and $y=a3/4$ we get

$\mathbb{E}_x[L_{T_a}^y]=-a/2$

so there is a contradiction. But where is the mistake?

It seems the assumption fails.
So how one can handle 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a}]$?.

It is quite strange here I used the same 
[expectation of stopped local time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705976/expectation-of-stopped-local-time)
and the result was true.

I know the Formula [expectation of stopped local time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705976/expectation-of-stopped-local-time)
holds true nevertheless my mistake (see site 171, Diffusion process and their sample path). 
Now let $a <x<y<b$ then we have

$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a \wedge T_b}]=2 \dfrac{(x-a)(b-y)}{(b-a)} \leq \mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a }] $

because the local time is increasing.
Now, we have 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a \wedge T_b}]
=2 \dfrac{(x-a)(b-y)}{(b-a)}= 2 \dfrac{b(x-a)(1-y/b)}{b(1-a/b)}= 2 \dfrac{(x-a)(1-y/b)}{(1-a/b)} \rightarrow 2 {(x-a)}$
for $b \rightarrow \infty$.
Now, the continuity of the local time, dominated convergence one obtains
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a}]=2(x-a)$.

We also have 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a \wedge T_b}]=2 \dfrac{a(x/a-1)(b-y)}{a(b/a-1)} =2 \dfrac{(x/a-1)(b-y)}{(b/a-1)} \rightarrow 2(b-y)$ for $a \rightarrow -\infty$.
This leads to 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{ T_b}]=2(b-y)$
By the way. 
I hope this computation is on the right way.
I need this to compute the walk Dimension for gap diffusions.

Comment: Instead of editing the question, it is better to post this as an answer to your own question (which is very normal). Also you should let $b\to-\infty$, not $a$; this would give $\mathbb E_x [L_y^{T_a}] = 2(a-x)$, which is not unexpected at all.

Comment: In my answer I change the order of $a$ and $x$ my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the integrand is bounded, the stochastic intergal is uniformly integrable. So $\int_0^{T_a}\operatorname{sgn}(B_s-y)\,dB_s$ has mean zero. The rest of your computation is fine.

Comment: Hmmm... The same reasoning would "prove" that $a=E_y(B_{T_a})=y$, which is obviously untrue.

Comment: So It is not a uniform integrable martingal?

Comment: Not, it is not.

Comment: Ok, this will explain the contradiction. Is there an other way to handle $\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a}]$?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I think I solved it.

Comment: My bad.  I should have said it's an $L^2$ martingale, but a small approximation argument is still needed.

Comment: What do you mean with small approximation argument ?

Comment: Replace $T_a$ by $R_n:=\min( T_a, T_z,n)$, where $z$ is far to the left of $y$. and take expectations:
$$
\Bbb E^x[|B_{R_n}-y|] -|x-y| = \Bbb E^x[L^y_{R_n}].
$$
The right side of this converges, as $n\to\infty$, to $\Bbb E^x[L^y_{\min(T_a, T_z)}]$ by monotone convergence. The left side converges, as $n\to\infty$, to $|a-y|\cdot \Bbb P^x[T_a<T_z]+|z-y|\cdot\Bbb P^x[T_z<T_a]-|x-y|$ by dominated convergence. From the well-known formula for hitting probabilities, this is equal to 
$$
|a-y|\cdot{x-z\over a-z}+|z-y|\cdot{a-x\over a-z}-|x-y|.
$$
Finally, let $z\to-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a <x<y<b$ then we have

$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a \wedge T_b}]=2 \dfrac{(x-a)(b-y)}{(b-a)} \leq \mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a }] $

because the local time is increasing.
Now, we have 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a \wedge T_b}]
=2 \dfrac{(x-a)(b-y)}{(b-a)}= 2 \dfrac{b(x-a)(1-y/b)}{b(1-a/b)}= 2 \dfrac{(x-a)(1-y/b)}{(1-a/b)} \rightarrow 2 {(x-a)}$
for $b \rightarrow \infty$.
Now, the continuity of the local time, monotone convergence one obtains
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a}]=2(x-a)$.

We also have 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{T_a \wedge T_b}]=2 \dfrac{a(x/a-1)(b-y)}{a(b/a-1)} =2 \dfrac{(x/a-1)(b-y)}{(b/a-1)} \rightarrow 2(b-y)$ for $a \rightarrow -\infty$.
This leads to 
$\mathbb{E}_x[L_y^{ T_b}]=2(b-y)$

Comment: Yes, but in OP, you have $y<x$. With this, the numerator would be $(y-a)(b-x)$, and the limit would become $2(b-x)$.